# Showing the Max values of a Sum

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sum, max

i am trying to find the max values of a sum result but i can not find a way to show the date too.
i have a table transactions which has data like this:

```
transaction_date--Transaction_agent_id--transaction_amount
2/5/11                         321      20
2/5/11                         321      10
2/5/11                         400      100
3/5/11                         321      5
3/5/11                         345      100
3/5/11                         321      10
3/5/11                         345      50
4/5/11                         345      80
4/5/11                         321      5
```

what i want the result to be is this

```
transaction_date--Transaction_agent_id--transaction_amount
    2/5/11                       321     30
    2/5/11                       400    100
    3/5/11                       345    150
```

What it should do is first of all to sum all the amount per agent_id, per day and then to show me the best day of that agent.

What i have done is this

```
SELECT a.transaction_agent_id, max(a.stotal) FROM
(
SELECT transaction_date,transaction_agent_id, sum(transaction_amount) as 'Stotal' FROM transactions
GROUP BY transaction_agent_id, transaction_date
)a
GROUP BY a.transaction_agent_id
```

which gives me this

```
Transaction_agent_id--transaction_amount
               321     30
               400    100
               345    150
```

which is correct but i can not add the transaction_date.

Update: I just solved it. Well if anyone wants the solution here it is.

```
SELECT  a.transaction_date, a.transaction_agent_id, max(a.stotal) FROM
(
  SELECT row_number() over (partition by transaction_agent_id order by sum(transaction_amount)desc) AS 'roww' ,transaction_date,transaction_agent_id, sum(transaction_amount) as 'Stotal' FROM transactions
  GROUP BY transaction_agent_id, transaction_date
) a

WHERE a.roww = 1
GROUP BY a.transaction_date, a.transaction_agent_id, a.roww
```

Thank you all for your input.

Comment: Your solution is needlessly complicated. The outer query's GROUP BY is absolutely superfluous and could be removed. Consequently, after the removal, `max(a.stotal)` should simply be `a.stotal`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SQL Statement**

```
;WITH Max_Transaction_Amount AS (
    SELECT  Transaction_Date
            , Transaction_Agent_ID
            , Transaction_Amount = SUM(Transaction_Amount)
    FROM    q
    GROUP BY
            Transaction_Date
            , Transaction_Agent_ID
)
SELECT  mta.Transaction_Date
        , mta.Transaction_Agent_ID
        , mta.Transaction_Amount
FROM    Max_Transaction_Amount mta 
        INNER JOIN (
            SELECT  Transaction_Agent_ID
                    , Transaction_Amount = MAX(Transaction_Amount)
            FROM    Max_Transaction_Amount
            GROUP BY
                    Transaction_Agent_ID        
        ) q ON  mta.Transaction_Agent_ID = q.Transaction_Agent_ID
                AND mta.Transaction_Amount = q.Transaction_Amount
```

**Test script**

```
/* Create test data */
;WITH q (Transaction_Date, Transaction_Agent_ID, Transaction_Amount) AS (
  SELECT '2/5/11',321,20
  UNION ALL SELECT '2/5/11',321,10
  UNION ALL SELECT '2/5/11',400,100
  UNION ALL SELECT '3/5/11',321,5
  UNION ALL SELECT '3/5/11',345,100
  UNION ALL SELECT '3/5/11',321,10
  UNION ALL SELECT '3/5/11',345,50
  UNION ALL SELECT '4/5/11',345,80
  UNION ALL SELECT '4/5/11',321,5
)
/* Actual query */
, Max_Transaction_Amount AS (
    SELECT  Transaction_Date
            , Transaction_Agent_ID
            , Transaction_Amount = SUM(Transaction_Amount)
    FROM    q
    GROUP BY
            Transaction_Date
            , Transaction_Agent_ID
)
SELECT  mta.Transaction_Date
        , mta.Transaction_Agent_ID
        , mta.Transaction_Amount
FROM    Max_Transaction_Amount mta 
        INNER JOIN (
            SELECT  Transaction_Agent_ID
                    , Transaction_Amount = MAX(Transaction_Amount)
            FROM    Max_Transaction_Amount
            GROUP BY
                    Transaction_Agent_ID        
        ) q ON  mta.Transaction_Agent_ID = q.Transaction_Agent_ID
                AND mta.Transaction_Amount = q.Transaction_Amount
```

Answer (score 0):

Just group by `transaction_date` in the outer select as well:

```
SELECT a.transaction_date, a.transaction_agent_id, max(a.stotal) FROM
(
  SELECT transaction_date,transaction_agent_id, sum(transaction_amount) as 'Stotal' FROM transactions
  GROUP BY transaction_agent_id, transaction_date
) a
GROUP BY a.transaction_agent_id, a.transaction_date
```

Comment: I have already try that. This will show all the sums per day while i need only the max.

Comment: I think we need more info on your keys for this table - I would expect this answer to work since it will give you the maximum for each individual date+agent combination.

Comment: Are you just looking for the max value by day regardless of the agent?

Comment: I need to find for every agent what was his best day. First i have to sum all his amounts per day (which is done as you see) and then to find the largest amount among all his days.Which is done in my query but without telling me which was that day.